# Possible to specify regions with Ansible "serial" param?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I'm running a rolling deploy on servers in ec2 through Ansible. I run the deploy on a few servers at a time using the `serial` parameter like so:

```
- name: run update
  hosts: tag_app_servers:&tag_active_servers
  serial: 7
  sudo: True
  pre_tasks:
  - name: Gathering ec2 facts
    action: ec2_facts
  # do the deregistration here
  roles:
  - some_role
  - some_other_role
  post_tasks:
  # re-register boxes here.
```

Thing is, Ansible thinks all my servers are the same (as it should), and doesn't differentiate between servers in different regions. So, whereas I'd like it to take one server from each of the 7 regions I'm in and run updates on those in parallel, Ansible can instead take 7 servers from just one region and completely cripple it. It's not a huge problem because traffic is just rerouted to other regions, but it's far from ideal. What would be a good way to force it to grab servers from different regions when running multiple server updates in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

With Ansible 1.x this simply isn't possible. When serializing a playbook it simply chops up the servers into arbitrary groups.

With Ansible 2.x it appears that [strategies](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_strategies.html) would do what you want, but you would probably have to write a custom strategy plugin to get the specific behavior you desire.

For now, with Ansible 1.x, you could just group your instances in such a way that each group has one server in each region, then run the playbook against each group one at a time.  It's a bit messy, but it would do what you want.